# How to register a function to be called before R script is exited

Tags: r, shutdown-hook

I'd like to do some cleanup work before the R process is exited by accidently. Is there any api like java's shutdown hook in R ? Thanks

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean, but perhaps `?on.exit` is intersting for you

Comment: `?reg.finalizer` may also be of interest

Answer (score 0):

Defining a  .Last function will do the trick.

```
.Last <- function() {
    printf("\n  == END of R | %s (runtime %s) ==\n", Sys.time(),format(round(difftime(Sys.time(), .r.start.time), 2)))
}
```

similarly .First function is called at the start of the script.

Comment: it seems .Last doesn't work for me. My scenario is that I am in R interactive session, and then I press ctrl + z to stop the R session. and I want to execute something before exit the R session.